# Creating thread does not work due to arguments being references

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm currently trying to make my first steps in writing multi-threaded code in CPP and I'm getting a error message that I don't understand at all....

Consider the two functions:

```cpp
void add_vector(std::vector<int> & vec, int & store){
    store = std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0);
}

int parallel_matrix_sum(std::vector<std::vector<int>> const & mat){
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::vector<int> tmp(l); 
    for (int k =0; k<l; k++){
        threads.push_back(std::thread(add_vector, std::cref(mat[k]), std::ref(tmp[k])));
    }

    for(auto && thread: threads){
        thread.join();
    }

    return std::accumulate(tmp.begin(), tmp.end(), 0);
}
```

The error I get is

```sh
error: attempt to use a deleted function
.
.
.
in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::thread::thread<void (&)(std::vector<int> &, int &), std::reference_wrapper<const std::vector<int>>, std::reference_wrapper<int>, void>' requested here
        threads.push_back(std::thread(add_vector, std::cref(mat[k]), std::ref(tmp[k])));
                          ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/type_traits:1916:5: note: '~__nat' has been explicitly marked deleted here
    ~__nat() = delete;
```

Upon googling this issue, all the information points to the fact that `std::thread` needs to copy the arguments, which cannot be done for references.. The suggested solution seems to be to wrap the arguments in a `std::ref` call. I am already doing this and it is still not working. Does anybody have some suggestions?

Comment: Maybe replace `std::cref` with `std::ref` as your references are not `const`? Actually `add_vector` expects a *non const* reference but you are passong a *const* reference!

Comment: Or change `std::vector<int> & vec` to `const std::vector<int> & vec` since there doesn't seem to be any need to modify `vec` in `add_vector`.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't have anything to do with the arguments being references? Have you tried extracting a [mcve] to further your understanding of the issue? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I did some playing. I got this to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void add_vector(const int & a, const int & b, int & c) {
    c = a + b;
}   

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    int a = 5;
    int b = 10;
    int c = 0;

    std::cout << "start threads.\n";

    threads.push_back(std::thread(add_vector, a, b, std::ref(c) ));

    std::cout << "Join.\n";
    for (std::thread &thread: threads) {
        thread.join();
    }

    std::cout << "Done. c == " << c << "\n";
}
```

This is with g++ using `--std=c++17`.

I updated this with info from Innocent Bystander. Passing by reference can work if you wrap in std::ref() as shown.

I'm going to try a fresh example with vectors.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void add_vector(const std::vector<int> & vec, int &result) {
    result = 0;
    for (const int &value: vec) {
        result += value;
    }
}   

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::vector<int> values;
    std::vector<int> results;

    values.push_back(10);
    values.push_back(15);
    results.push_back(0);

    std::cout << "start threads.\n";

    threads.push_back(std::thread(add_vector, values, std::ref(results[0]) )); 

    std::cout << "Join.\n";
    for (std::thread &thread: threads) {
        thread.join();
    }

    std::cout << "Done. c == " << results[0] << "\n";
}
```

This above with vector works. I didn't wrap the first args. I did wrap the final one.

The end answer: take a look at the very first argument to your method. It isn't listed as const.

Comment: Joseph, you just need to wrap `c` in `std::ref` and you can pass by reference. See here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e3b7cf9fd7cb9a7

Comment: @InnocentBystander updating my answer...

Comment: Jo, the problem is that he's passing `mat` by const ref to `parallel_matrix_sum`. So, he needs to change `add_vector` signature to take `vec` by const ref as well, which is what you did in your example.

Comment: @InnocentBystander I presume you were about to reference the const vs. non-const thing. See the end of my answer.

Comment: Oh right. Sorry, just glanced at your answer.

Comment: @InnocentBystander No worries -- it took me making sure it wasn't something hard before realizing it was something easy.